# Change current Realtime Database location

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently a new region was added for Realtime Database location, europe-west1.

I understand that if I want to move my instance, I could make a second instance and do the move manually. This means coming up with a new name for the new instance, because choosing the same name is not allowed.

Is there a way currently or on the roadmap to migrate the database, keeping its name? A little downtime would not be a problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I got a message that I could not upvote because I am not reputable enough. I didn't know I am able to checkmark it. Your answer is what I hoped for; being sure that I wasn't missing anything and that it is in fact not (yet) possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

It is currently not possible to move a database instance to another region. You'll have to add a new instance to the same project and *create* that in the region.

The plan is to allow moving existing instances, but as usual: we won't make predictions on when (or even if) that will be available.